# How to authenticate user with Fuelphp REST?

Tags: rest, fuelphp

I am new to Fuel PHP... I am working on a project with REST architecture in Fuelphp..... I didn't found any tutorial how to achieve the required functionality "User Authentication using Fuel PHP REST".

As REST server is stateless how do we use auth package of fuelphp in rest api?

Answer (score 1):

As you also pointed, REST calls are somewhat stateless meaning you have no session to store.

The auth documentation has some methods which checks user credentials, but does not store authentication. There are no offical way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

One of the methods that I have used in the past is to use a token based system. You have an API token linked to an Auth user then this token is supplied in the `Authorize` header when making a request, the token is then checked against known tokens and if valid a forced login is performed with the Auth package.

Comment: If you need to use forced login in a rest API you are doing something wrong, because that means you are also storing a session, which should not be done in API calls. One check of the credentials should be enough. If you need to be able to check authentication/authorization multiple times (for example check permissions), you should use a noop session driver (for example one storing things in array) which only lives with the request, but does not get persisted.

Comment: The only reason I use a forced login is to be able to use the usual Auth interfaces without issue. Auth does store a session but you cannot stop that, it's still a stateless api as it's (in theroy) not storing the log in between calls. Currently with fuel's default auth drivers it's impossible to avoid that.

Comment: It is not impossible. As I said, you can use a dummy session driver which does not persist the session data. Also, you only need force login if you need more than authentication check. AFAIK you can check the credentials without logging in. Thus if you don't need for example authorization (ACL) then you don't need logging in. If you are interested: I am playing around with a new perspective of authentication. So far I have done: https://github.com/guardianphp